# Does biphasic wave mean current is bidirectional?

Tags: current, polarity, waveform

[image: wave]

Does biphasic wave mean current is going bidirectional in a circuit?

Comment: Please spend some quality time with your question, it could use a little more explanation *and* a little more formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From what I can see,](http://www.resuscitationcentral.com/defibrillation/biphasic-waveform/) yes, the current flows in two directions during different parts of the defibrillation impulse.  That is, there is a polarity reversal.

See the diagram on the linked site:
[image]